# KNN Model, cannot import from Windows. What to do for Raspberry pi with Low RAM

Tags: pi-2

I have a raspberry pi 2b with 1 GB of RAM.
I want to train an ML model with about 6k images.

I followed https://github.com/kevinzakka/blog-code/blob/master/knn/knn.py and I have a model that works well, and can create the model for 2k images, but I run into RAM and memory issues when I try to do about 6k.

I can create a 20k image model on a PC, but cannot transfer the model to the PI because of the different architecture not being supported problem here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

So I have to build it on the PI but I don't have the RAM to build the model.

Are there ways to get around this, either by some special way to port a model or by retraining the same knn with new data?